# Discord.py- How to make the bot not interact with DMs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nonetype

I am writing a small message logging program; I want the bot to only log messages from a specific guild, so I check for the `message.guild.id`. This, however, raises a problem when there is a message sent in a DM Channel. I want the bot to ignore the DM channel completely, but am not having much luck.

The Code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.guild.id == Guild ID HERE:
            print(f"{message.author} said --- {message.clean_content} --- in #{message.channel.name}")
        elif message.channel.type is discord.ChannelType.private:
            pass
```

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Documents\Bots\DS BOT\cog\Listener.py", line 13, in on_message
    if message.guild.id == Guild ID HERE:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Documents\Bots\DS BOT\cog\Logger.py", line 12, in on_message
    if message.guild.id == Guild ID HERE:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: `if message.guild is None: return`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do

```
if message.guild:
   # message is from a server
else:
   # message is from a dm.
```

That's it. There's no need of checking for types.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the channel is private before doing your guild check otherwise it will raise an error. This should do the job:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
            return
        if message.guild.id == Guild ID HERE:
            print(f"{message.author} said --- {message.clean_content} --- in #
```

Comment: Sorry, but this changed nothing

Comment: Are you sure you did everything correctly? I've just tried it myself and it works as intended.

Comment: Here is my full code https://hastebin.com/aqedusugar.py

Comment: I removed the guild check for me but otherwise, it works just fine with this code https://hastebin.com/ekosoxikud.py

Comment: Huh I looked over the code over and over, but I am still getting the same error in the code when I send a DM even when I copy-paste your code, do you have any more advice. Also thanks for the help
The bot works fine logging messages from  guilds but screws up in DM's

Comment: You could also try checking channel type `print(type(message.channel))` and comparing `message.channel` with this type instead of `discord.DMChannel`. Maybe consider updating your discord.py, maybe it's the problem.

Comment: I have the newest version so that cant be it

Comment: It is saver to use `if message.guild is None: return` than checking against DMChannel.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was simple. At the time I set up a custom prefix system that would give every server the bot is in its own default prefix which could be later changed. The thing with Dm's is that it's not a server and therefore was not in the prefix database causing the error.

This was solved with:

```
def get_prefix(bot, message):
    if (message.guild is None):
        return '.'
    else:
        with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)
        return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
```

Simply if the message or command that was received was not sent from a server, it would simply use the default prefix

Answer (score -1):

Pass this inside your `if` statement:

```py
if message.channel.type is discord.ChannelType.private: 
    return
```

This should work for you!