# How do I make my discord.py bot not react to dms?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do I make a discord.py bot not react to commands from the bot's DMs? I only want the bot to respond to messages if they are on a specific channel on a specific server.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63105018/discord-py-making-the-bot-not-interact-with-dm-channels

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py Making the bot not interact with DM channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63105018/discord-py-making-the-bot-not-interact-with-dm-channels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to only respond to messages on a specific channel and you know the name of the channel, you could do this:

```
channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="channel name")
channel_id = channel.id
```

Then you would check if the id matched the one channel you wanted it to be in. To get a channel or server's id, you need to enable [discord developer mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/714348/how-to-enable-or-disable-developer-mode-on-discord/). After than you could just right click on the server or channel and copy the id.

To get a server's id you need to add this piece of code as a command:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def getguild(ctx):
    id = ctx.message.guild.id # the guild is the server
    # do something with the id (print it out)
```

After you get the server id, you can delete the method.

And to check if a message is sent by a person or a bot, you could do this in the on_message method:

```
def on_message(self, message):
    if (message.author.bot):
        # is a bot
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

**You Can Use Simplest And Best Way**

```py
@bot.command()
async def check(ctx):
    if not isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel):
       Your Work...
```

Comment: "Simplest and best way" is a very bold claim! What about `if ctx.guild`?

Comment: ctx.guild is not simplest

Comment: I would argue that it is, given that it's the shortest one. It's also pretty clear what you're checking with this.

Answer (score 1):

So just to make the bot not respond to DMs, add this code after each command:

```
if message.guild:
  # Message comes from a server.
else:
  # Message comes from a DM.
```

This makes it better to separate DM from server messages. You just now have to move the "await message.channel.send" function.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are asking for a bot that only listens to your commands. Well, in that case, you can create a check to see if the message is sent by you or not. It can be done using,

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author.id == <#your user id>:
    await message.channel.send('message detected')
    ...#your code
```